# add notice/message to woocommerce custom add to cart shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make a WooCommerce add to cart shortcode with qty field. My code works fine but when click on add to cart no message/ notice is not showing. How can I add this please help. also how to achieve this without reload page like shop/archive page add to cart button.

```
function elm_add_to_cart_shortcode(){
    global $product;
    $_product_id = 655;
    $elm_html = '';
    if(class_exists('Woocommerce')) {
        if ( ! is_shop() && ! is_product_taxonomy() ) {
        //Start Construct the shortcode html output
        ob_start();
        $elm_html .= '<div class="elm_add_to_cart_wrp">';
        $elm_html .= '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $elm_html .= '<div class="elm_quantity quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" value="-" class="minus">';
        $elm_html .= '<input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">';
        $elm_html .= '<input type="button" value="+" class="plus">';
        $elm_html .= '</div>';
        $elm_html .= '<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value='.$_product_id.' class="elm_button fusion-button button-default button-large single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>';
        $elm_html .= '</form>';
        $elm_html .= '</form>';
        return $elm_html ;
        ob_end_clean();

        }
    //==========================================================
    wc_enqueue_js( "
        jQuery( '.add_to_cart_inline .qty' ).on( 'change', function() {
            var qty = jQuery( this ),
                atc = jQuery( this ).next( '.add_to_cart_button' );
                atc.attr( 'data-quantity', qty.val() );
        });
    " );
    //==========================================================
    }
}

add_shortcode('elmaddtocart','elm_add_to_cart_shortcode');
```

Comment: what do you mean by `no message/ notice is not showing`

Comment: @madalinivascu when add to cart click no message/ notification shown about that the product is added or not. but technically it added to cart.

Comment: you altered the add to cart button so your mini cart list doesn't update automatically, you need to add the product via javascript in the mini cart list

Comment: is there any example ? using javascript? I have used `wc_print_notices();` to display right now